# Method Not Allowed(405 POST) in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

This is my `index.html`:

```
<form action="{% url 'request:my_shipment' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value="My shipment"/>
</form>
```

This is my `urls.py`:

```
app_name = 'request'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', request_views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('create_request/', request_views.RequestView.as_view(), name="request"),
    path('request/<int:pk>', request_views.UpdateReceiveView.as_view(), name='receive'),
    path('my_shipment/', request_views.ListMyShipment.as_view(), name='my_shipment')
]
```

This is my `views.py`:

```
class ListMyShipment(ListView):
    template_name = 'request/my_shipment.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return models.Shipment.objects.filter(shipper_id=self.request.user.id)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['user_list'] = models.User.objects.all()
        context['user_id'] = self.request.user.id
        return context
```

And this is a respond when I click to `My shipment`button:

```
Method Not Allowed (POST): /my_shipment/
```

I am using Django version 2.0.5

Comment: can you add `ListMyShipment` view?

Comment: It is not respond 405 when I refresh page again

Comment: @QuocHuy  you have to define post function to make a post request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Django class based view you have to write methods like get, post, put etc.. unless you write post functions you will not be able to call that view in post method.

```
class ListMyShipment(View):
    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
         #your Code For post, **kwargs, request are not essential
```

you can learn more about class based views post method here,
[class Based Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/#handling-forms-with-class-based-views)

Comment: can you add ListMyShipment view?

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked but I don't understand how to it work

Comment: @QuocHuy internally a view will call type of method based on type of request made.